# Canvas with Ellipses in Border with rounded corners

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

```
<Border ClipToBounds="True" CornerRadius=20>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        </Canvas>
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

[image: What i have]
How to prevent canvas content rendering outside of Border?

**UPD:** Thanks for ur unswers. Found solution:
Use it except Border. Opacity masks won't with Canvas geometry, unfortunately :(

> None of the decorators (i.e. Border) or layout panels (i.e.
>   Stackpanel) come with this behavior out-of-the-box.
>
> ClipToBounds is for layout. ClipToBounds does not prevent an element
>   from drawing outside its bounds; it just prevents children's layouts
>   from 'spilling'.
>
> Additionally ClipToBounds=True is not needed for most elements because
>   their implementations dont allow their content's layout to spill
>   anyway. The most notable exception is Canvas.
>
> Finally Border considers the rounded corners to be drawings inside the
>   bounds of its layout.

```
public class ClippingBorder : Border
    {
        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            OnApplyChildClip();
            base.OnRender(dc);
        }

    public override UIElement Child
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Child;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Child != value)
            {
                if (Child != null)
                {
                    // Restore original clipping
                    Child.SetValue(ClipProperty, _oldClip);
                }

                if (value != null)
                {
                    _oldClip = value.ReadLocalValue(ClipProperty);
                }
                else
                {
                    // If we dont set it to null we could leak a Geometry object
                    _oldClip = null;
                }

                base.Child = value;
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnApplyChildClip()
    {
        UIElement child = Child;
        if (child != null)
        {
            _clipRect.RadiusX = _clipRect.RadiusY = Math.Max(0.0, this.CornerRadius.TopLeft - (this.BorderThickness.Left * 0.5));
            _clipRect.Rect = new Rect(Child.RenderSize);
            child.Clip = _clipRect;
        }
    }

    private RectangleGeometry _clipRect = new RectangleGeometry();
    private object _oldClip;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and somewhere I found that the answer was to use an OpacityMask with ScrollViewer. Try the following:

```
    <Grid>
    <Border ClipToBounds="True" CornerRadius="20"
            Background="Green">
        <Border.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Border Background="Green"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Border}}"
                            Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"
                            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Border}}"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Border.OpacityMask>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Canvas>
                <Ellipse Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100" Canvas.Left="-37" Canvas.Top="-26"/>
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: Canvas rounded corners]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The ScrollViewer is entirely redundant. Remove it and set the Canvas' ClipToBounds property to true.

Comment: Thanks for tips, but this can't help me, unfortunately, i need different colors and dynamic shapes on canvas. Opacity mask doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 0):

In case the Border has a fixed size, you could simply set its `Clip` property to an appropriate RectangleGeometry:

```
<Border CornerRadius="20" Background="Green">
    <Border.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Rect="0,0,100,50"/>
    </Border.Clip>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        </Canvas>
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Unfortunately you can't bind the `Rect` property of the RectangleGeometry without a binding converter.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `Border.ClipToBounds="True"`, its contents will in fact be clipped to its bounds, however said "bounds" do not take into account the `Border.CornerRadius` - bounds are basically a rectangle of size stemming from `Border.ActualWidth` and `Border.ActualHeight` (this is true not only for `Border`, but for any element derived from `UIElement`).

If you need to clip the contents of a `Border` to a custom shape (and round corners fall into that category) you should specify the clipping geometry through the `Border.Clip` property (as mentioned by @Clemens in his answer).

Now depending on a variety of conditions you could come up with solutions with varying complexity, but let me introduce a **universal** solution. The idea is to create an appropriate geometry basing on the size and corner radii of the `Border`. In order to accomplish that we'll create an `IMultiValueConverter` and wire it using `MultiBinding`. Here's the complete converter:

```
public class ClipConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var width = (double)values[0];
        var height = (double)values[1];
        if (width == 0 || height == 0) return null;
        var corners = (CornerRadius)values[2];

        //First we calculate break points in case corner radii exceed
        //the size of the Border - this is done in a proportional manner
        var topBreak = width * corners.TopLeft / (corners.TopLeft + corners.TopRight);
        var rightBreak = height * corners.TopRight / (corners.TopRight + corners.BottomRight);
        var bottomBreak = width * corners.BottomLeft / (corners.BottomLeft + corners.BottomRight);
        var leftBreak = height * corners.TopLeft / (corners.TopLeft + corners.BottomLeft);

        //Let's name interesting points on the path:
        //    0-------1  
        //   /         \
        //  7           2
        //  |           |
        //  6           3
        //   \         /
        //    5-------4
        //We need to take into account the break points
        var p0 = new Point(Math.Min(corners.TopLeft, topBreak), 0);
        var p1 = new Point(Math.Max(width - corners.TopRight, topBreak), 0);
        var p2 = new Point(width, Math.Min(corners.TopRight, rightBreak));
        var p3 = new Point(width, Math.Max(height - corners.BottomRight, rightBreak));
        var p4 = new Point(Math.Max(width - corners.BottomRight, bottomBreak), height);
        var p5 = new Point(Math.Min(corners.BottomLeft, bottomBreak), height);
        var p6 = new Point(0, Math.Max(height - corners.BottomLeft, leftBreak));
        var p7 = new Point(0, Math.Min(corners.TopLeft, leftBreak));

        var geometry = new StreamGeometry();

        //Draw the geometry using a StreamGeometryContext object
        var context = geometry.Open();

        context.BeginFigure(p0, true, true);
        if (p1 != p0)
            context.LineTo(p1, false, false);
        context.ArcTo(p2, new Size(p2.Y, width - p1.X), 90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, false, false);
        if (p3 != p2)
            context.LineTo(p3, false, false);
        context.ArcTo(p4, new Size(height - p3.Y, width - p4.X), 90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, false, false);
        if (p5 != p4)
            context.LineTo(p5, false, false);
        context.ArcTo(p6, new Size(height - p6.Y, p5.X), 90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, false, false);
        if (p7 != p6)
            context.LineTo(p7, false, false);
        context.ArcTo(p0, new Size(p7.Y, p0.X), 90, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, false, false);

        //Close the context so that the geometry can be rendered
        context.Close();

        return geometry;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Border (...)>
    <Border.Resources>
        <local:ClipConverter x:Key="ClipConverter" />
    </Border.Resource>
    <Border.Clip>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ClipConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding Path="CornerRadius" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Border.Clip>
    (...)
</Border>
```